# Unable to get artifact com.elsevier:spark-xml-utils:jar:1.6.0

Tags: xml, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to utilize the capabilities provided by the spark-xml-utils library within an Apache Spark application. I am unable to get the spark-xml-utils library in my mavenized spark-scala project. My pom.xml config is: -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.alpha.beta</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <name>spark2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/elsevierlabs-os/spark-xml-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.elsevier</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-xml-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId> maven-scala-plugin </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange> [2.15.2,) </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get a missing artifact com.elsevier:spark-xml-utils:jar:1.6.0 error. Am I doing something wrong? I am sure that it's not a network or firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

The group id is wrong -it should be **elsevierlabs-os** not **com.elsevier**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>elsevierlabs-os</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```